# Prove $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$ converges for all $x \in R$

Tags: convergence-divergence, exponential-function

So, I proved that $\big((1+\frac{x}{n})^n\big)_{n\in N}$ converges for $x\in$ $[0,1]$ (call it fact (1)) and that $\lim_{n\to \infty} |(1+\frac{a}{n})^n - (1+\frac{a}{n} + \frac{b}{n^2})^n| = 0$ for any $a, b\in$ R (call it fact (2)).

Now, the question I'm solving requires me to prove the convergence of $\big((1+\frac{x}{n})^n\big)_{n\in N}$ for all real numbers using specifically these two facts. Both of them.

Some ideas and tools I considered using, but couldn't make it work were the Binomial Expansion and using convergence tests as the comparison test. More specifically, I considered comparing the above sequence with $\big((1+\frac{1}{n})^n\big)_{n\in N}$ .

Any help appreciated.

Comment: $(1+(x/n))^n=((1+(1/(n/x))^{n/x})^x=((1+(1/m))^m)^x$.

Comment: That's a nice trick and it definitely solves it, but the question I'm solving explicitly asks one to use both facts I presented (edited question to make this more explicit). Something at the root of my question is, what deep thing is fact (2) saying, I'm guessing that'd help with the solution.

Comment: Wish I could help, but I don't see how to use (2) here, either. Sorry.